# Date addition formula javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on invoice generation program in php. In it I am using datetimepicker to use the invoice generation date and due date. Now I want due date field to be auto-filled by adding a specific value to the invoice generation date feild. Following is my html :

```
<div class = "col-lg-4">
                <select id = "invoice_duration"  class="form-control input-group placeholder">
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>40</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                </select>
                </div><br><br>

                <div class = "col-lg-6">
                    <h4> Invoice Date </h4>
                     <div class="input-append date datetimepicker">
                      <input id = "invoice_date" style = "height : 35px;" style = "height : 30px;" style = "height : 30px;"  type="text" name = "invoice_date">
                      <span style = "height : 35px;" class="add-on">
                        <i style = "padding-top:5px;" data-time-icon="fa fa-time" data-date-icon="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </span>
                    </div>                      
                </div>


                <div class = "col-lg-6">
                <h4> Due Date </h4>
                    <div class="input-append date datetimepicker">
                        <input id = "due_date" style = "height : 35px;" style = "height : 30px;"  type="text" name = "due_date">
                        <span style = "height : 35px;" class="add-on">
                            <i style = "padding-top:5px;" data-time-icon="fa fa-time" data-date-icon="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And my script is as follow :

```
<script>
    $( "#due_date" ).click(function() {

        var invoice_date = $("#invoice_date").val();
        var invoice_duration = $("#invoice_duration").val();

        var splited_invoice_date = invoice_date.split("/");
        var day = splited_invoice_date[0];
        var month = splited_invoice_date[1];
        var year = splited_invoice_date[2];
        var total_days = (+year_days) + (+month_days) + (+days);
        alert('day :' +day+ 'Month :' +month+ 'Year :' +year);

        });
```

Using this I am successfully getting the alert giving me segregated date. Now is there an easy of adding the value from the "select" field and adding it to the invoice_generation_date to finally get something to put in the due_date field.

Basically I want a date addition formula. Sorry if I am ambiguous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have a look at http://momentjs.com/ for your date related needs. PS. what is going on with those style attributes?

Comment: Thank you Andy, I accomplished it using moment.js. haha, those attributes just looked at them. Actually gave one of my students a task to create a form. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I would trigger the event on change of the previous field, not the enter click.

The easiest way to add days in js is to use seconds in a day and then use the formatting primitives.

Something like this should work:

```
$("#invoice_date").change(function(){
   var invoice_date = $("#invoice_date").val();
   var invoice_duration = parseInt($("#invoice_duration").val(),10);

   var d = new Date(invoice_date).getTime()+(invoice_duration*24*60*60*1000);
   d = new Date(d);
   var dFormatted =  d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();

   $("#due_date").val(dFormatted).trigger('click');
 });
```

The click trigger at the end is to open the cal popout.   you can remove that if you don't want it to happen automatically.

simpler fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/16gov1ms/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time of explaining along with the demo. However it does'nt seem to working when the month value is changed like in your example if I change '01/01/2015' to something like '04/01/2015' the answer distorts. Also I have accomplished using moment.js plugin but your method is way more thorough and manipulatable. Thank you again.

Comment: The distortion you see is likely from the format.  The format is UK style date, "4th of January" not "January 4th"  Your example implied that dimension with `var day = splited_invoice_date[0];`   either way, glad you got it working.